# how to retain height using angular-gridster?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui, gridster

I was racking my brain trying the get the `.gridster-mobile` class to preserve the height. It currently disregards `min_size[0]` when in mobile due to the height being set to empty string.

I had a temporary fix where I just set all the heights with a media query:

```
@media (max-width: 500px) {
  .gridster-item{
    height:120px !important;
  }
}
```

and this is the gridster settings:

```
      isMobile: false, // stacks the grid items if true
      mobileBreakPoint: 600, // if the screen is not wider that this, remove the grid layout and stack the items
      mobileModeEnabled: true,
```

How to preserve the row height when in mobile mode?

Answer (score 3):

I posted this question because I did not find the answer, which is this less-documented configuration setting:

```
saveGridItemCalculatedHeightInMobile:true
```

this should save you some headache. In the example config, this is way down the list away from the other mobile settings, so it's easy to overlook.